# Debugging MirrorsUsed

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-mirrors

I'm trying to figure out which libraries I need to pass to `@MirrorsUsed` to get my app compiled and working.  Sometimes, it's easy to figure out which library may be missing since a descriptive error is thrown such as `Uncaught Unsupported operation: Cannot find class for: NgAttr` .

Other times, I get a more obscure message, such as `NullError: Cannot call "$gt" on null` with no clue as to which library I may be omitting.  Is there a better approach to this, besides trial and error?

In case you're wondering, this is an angular app and this is how I currently have it configured:

```dart
@MirrorsUsed(targets: const[
                        'angular',
                        'angular.core',
                        'angular.core.dom',
                        'angular.filter',
                        'angular.perf',
                        'angular.directive',
                        'angular.routing',
                        'angular.core.parser.dynamic_parser', 
                        'angular.core.parser.lexer',
                        'todo',
                        'perf_api',
                        'List',
                        'NodeTreeSanitizer',
                        'PlaybackHttpBackendConfig'
                        ],
                        override: '*')
import 'dart:mirrors';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
pub build --mode=debug
```

this does tree shaking but retains (mostly) the original Dart names.
Then debugging the generated JavaScript usually lets deduce the source of the exception.

**EDIT**

IMHO these are not necessary anymore, because they were added to `@MirrorsUsed` in the Angular libs.

```
                    'angular',
                    'angular.core',
                    'angular.core.dom',
                    'angular.filter',
                    'angular.perf',
                    'angular.directive',
                    'angular.routing',
                    'angular.core.parser.dynamic_parser', 
                    'angular.core.parser.lexer',
```

Comment: Yep, I've been doing this is debug mode.

Comment: It can still be quite vague I agree. Mirrors need major help...I'm really hoping it can be more automated in future. When you're coding your own thing it's not so bad, but when you start pulling in 3rd party libraries you can really get into trouble. For example - angular.dart.ui ... I'm stuck on the modal module and mirrors. I'm spending hours adding new packages to the annotation and building trial and error style the traces aren't super helpful.